# How to load single user control on selection of a tab in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I got 15 tabs and 15 user controls assigned to each tab.
All are loading at once which id delaying the process.
I want to load one user control on selection of a tab in tab container.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding all controls declaratively on the page, add them programmatically on the tab  change event. See this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86.aspx

Or here's the short version..

1. Change the Register declaration at the top of the page, to a reference:

   <%@ Reference Control="MyUserControl.ascx" %>
2. In your tab change event, load the the uc from file:

   Dim uc As MyUserControl = CType(LoadControl("MyUserControl.ascx"), MyUserControl)
3. Add the control to the page:

   PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc)

Comment: Please clarify the tab change event.
Is it the TabContainerSettings_ActiveTabChanged?
There are tab changed events for a particular tab.

Comment: Yes, that's assuming you are using AJAX control toolkit.

Comment: Thanks.
But got one problem.
when i click on a tab the controls are showing up and disappearing again.

Comment: Sounds like something else, other than selecting a tab, may be causing a second postback. Hard to tell w/o seeing the rest of the code. When  the control disappears, are you still left on the same tab or returned to the default one?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete solution. The markup...

```
<%@ Reference Control="~/MyUserControl.ascx" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

<asp:TabContainer ID="TabContainer1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
    <asp:TabPanel id="Tab1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            Tab1
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ContentTemplate>
            Tab 1 static content
        </ContentTemplate>                
    </asp:TabPanel>
    <asp:TabPanel id="Tab2" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            Tab2
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ContentTemplate>
            <!-- user control will be loaded here -->
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:TabPanel>
</asp:TabContainer>
```

...and codebehind:

```
Protected Sub TabContainer1_ActiveTabChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TabContainer1.ActiveTabChanged
    If TabContainer1.ActiveTabIndex = 1 Then
        Dim uc As MyUserControl = CType(LoadControl("MyUserControl.ascx"), MyUserControl)
        Tab2.Controls.Add(uc)
    End If
End Sub
```